# Bootstrap Menu rendering under LayerSlider slideshow

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-7

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and [LayerSlider](http://codecanyon.net/item/layerslider-responsive-jquery-slider-plugin/discussion/922100) - I have a dropdown menu un the main nav on my page, and it is above the slider.  When I drop down the menu, it renders behind the slider.  This happens only in IE7, and I need it to work in IE7... any ideas/suggestions?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
position: relative; z-index:10000;
```

to the main  div that contains the bootstrap menu.